# Why is the git pre-receive hook not detecting puppet-lint?

Tags: git, hook, bundler, githooks, rbenv

I'm using the [drwahl/puppet-git-hooks](https://github.com/drwahl/puppet-git-hooks/blob/master/pre-receive).

I have `puppet-lint` installed on my local machine however when I do my `git push origin puppet_hook` I get the following output:

```
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 345 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Checking puppet manifest syntax for manifests/init.pp...
remote: Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '}' at manifests/init.pp:3
remote: Error: puppet syntax error in manifests/init.pp (see above)
remote: Error: 1 syntax error(s) found in puppet manifests. Commit will be aborted.
remote: puppet-lint not installed. Skipping puppet-lint tests...
remote: Error: 1 subhooks failed. Declining push.
remote: Hook /var/tmp/hooks/pre-receive.puppet failed with error code 1
```

As you can see it says:

`remote: puppet-lint not installed. Skipping puppet-lint tests...`

When I traced it to the pre-receive script (provided above) I found the following check:

```
 #puppet manifest styleguide compliance
        if [ "$CHECK_PUPPET_LINT" != "disabled" ] ; then
            if type puppet-lint >/dev/null 2>&1; then
                if [ $(echo $changedfile | grep -q '\.*.pp$' ; echo $?) -eq 0 ]; then
                    ${subhook_root}/puppet_lint_checks.sh $CHECK_PUPPET_LINT $tmpmodule "${tmptree}/"
                    RC=$?
                    if [ "$RC" -ne 0 ]; then
                        failures=`expr $failures + 1`
                    fi
                fi
            else
                echo "puppet-lint not installed. Skipping puppet-lint tests..."
            fi
        fi
```

It seems to be failing at:

`if type puppet-lint >/dev/null 2>&1; then`

When I run the above command locally it is successful.

Why is not detecting `puppet-lint` via the pre-receive script?

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that `puppet-lint` is a command that's accessible on your PATH?

Comment: `which puppet-lint` shows me the following:
`/Users/aca/.rbenv/shims/puppet-lint`

however `whereis puppet-lint` was empty so i made a symlink: `/usr/bin/puppet-lint` to `/Users/aca/.rbenv/shims/puppet-lint` yet it still does not work.

Comment: Is remote origin located on your machine or on a remote machine?

Comment: @joran: remote server. It seems to run syntax checker fine so its definitely hitting it.

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan can you verfy that puppet-lint is available on remote server and executable by your remote user (which user depends on how you cloned the repo)?

Comment: @joran: I think my misunderstanding was that the pre-receive hooks execs need to reside on client machine. Doubt cleared!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the server that you're going on to. The user that you're running this as may not have the alias set up, or have `puppet-lint` in the path.